# deletion on B+ tree

Tags: b-tree

As a student, I've been trying to implement B+ tree in C myself. The insert is ok but the deletion holds me off. One of my questions is this:
Is it ok to remain a key in the internal node while its key in the leaf node has been deleted?
This may happen when the internal node is not the leaf's parent.
Is my description clear enough? Does any one have similar experiences?

Comment: Do you want a yes or no answer? Is this homework?

Comment: "Is it ok to remain a key..."  Do you mean "leave a key..."?  This sentence threw me off.

Answer (score 3):

The question you should ask yourself when working with a data structure is, "What are the invariants?"  For a B+ tree, some of the invariants are:

- Records are stored in the leaf nodes,
- Leaf nodes must be at least half full.

So if you decide that B+ trees allow you to keep keys that no longer correspond to records, that's fine.  Just make sure that your insertion and search algorithms still work given your particular set of invariants.

In general, it is somewhat bizarre to encounter a key in any kind of tree that does not correspond to one of the records.  I'd also expect the cost for correcting it in a B+ tree with large fanout to be fairly small.